# How to insert struct into stl::map C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, insert

I am trying to use a loop to populate a map using the insert method. I have a map that I am trying to populate using this method:

```
void board:: insertToMap(Letter c, int num){
    this->myRackMap.insert(pair<Letter, int>(c, num));
}
```

and I call this helper method in this loop within another method:

```
void board:: getRackAsMap(){
    for (int i = 0; i < this->getMyRack().size(); ++i){
        insertToMap(this->getMyRack().at(i), this->getMyRack().at(i).readScore());
    }
}
//myRackMap is a map<Letter, int>
//myRack is a vector<Letter>

vector<Letter>& board::getMyRack(){
    return this->myRack;
}

//readScore returns an Int value based on the char value of the current Letter
```

When I try to run this I get a ridiculously long error message, waaay too long to put into this. The ending line of the error message is this; however:

> "‘const Letter’ is not derived from ‘const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp,
>   _Compare, _Alloc>’
>          { return __x < __y; }"

which led me to believe that the error is related to inserting my struct Letter into the map instead of a primitive data type. Any advice would be greatly appreciated as I am not too familiar with c++, thank you for any help you can provide!

EDIT: here is what Letter.h looks like

```
struct Letter{
private:
    char theLetter;
    int xPos;
    int yPos;
public:
    Letter();
    Letter(char c);
    Letter(int x, int y, char c);
    void setPos(int x, int y);
    void setLetter(char c);
    int getXPos();
    int getYPos();
    char getTheLetter();
    int readScore();
};
```

and letter.cpp

```
Letter:: Letter(){
    this->xPos = -1;
    this->yPos = -1;
    this->theLetter = '?';
}

Letter:: Letter(char c){
    this->xPos = -1;
    this->yPos = -1;
    this->theLetter = c;
}

Letter:: Letter(int x, int y, char c){
    this->xPos = x;
    this->yPos = y;
    this->theLetter = c;
}
int Letter:: getXPos(){
    return this->xPos;
}
int Letter:: getYPos(){
    return this->yPos; 
} 
char Letter:: getTheLetter(){
    return this->theLetter;
}
void Letter:: setPos(int x, int y){
    this->xPos = x;
    this->yPos = y;
}
void Letter:: setLetter(char c){
    this->theLetter = c;
}
int Letter:: readScore(){
    switch (this->getTheLetter()){
        case 'A':
        return 1;
        break;
    case 'B':
        return 3;
        break;
    //etc etc, returns int based on char of Letter
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to define an `operator<` for your key. In your case that would be `Letter`.

Comment: @simpel01 what would the body of the code look like in the < operator overload? I am not really sure how to proceed with this, but thank you for the assistance!

Comment: We need to know how `Letter` looks like.

Comment: @simpel01 I updated the post in ordre to include this information, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements of a `std::map` are ordered based on the `key`. Therefore you need to either define an `operator<` for your key object, which in your example is `Letter`. Or provide a comparator when the `std::map` is built.

```
bool cmp(const Letter& lhs, const Letter &rhs) { ...define order... }
std::map<Letter, int, bool(*)(const Letter&, const Letter&)> myRackMap(cmp);
```

Whatever solution you decide to use you need to define a way to order your letters, I suppose the combination of `xpos`, `ypos` define an unique identifier for `Letter`s. Therefore you can write something like this:

```
bool cmp(const Letter& lhs, const Letter &rhs) {
   return std::tie(lhs.xPos, lhs.yPos) < std::tie(rhs.xPos, rhs.yPos);
}
```

Or if you choose to overload the `<` operator:

```
bool Letter::operator<(const Letter &other) const {
   return std::tie(xPos, yPos) < std::tie(other.xPos, other.yPos);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help

Comment: is there a way I could populate the map in similar fashion but without using a cmp or < overload? The order of the Letters in the map has no real meaning, they could be put in there randomly as long as the letter had the proper int assigned to it. The only reason I even have it as a map is because I am writing code that has to fit a method that my professor gave me, but if this is the only way to accomplish this task I will try to make it work. Once again thank you!

Comment: If you don't care about eliminating duplicates and order you can use a vector, `std::vector<std::pair<Letter, int>>` and use `push_back` instead of insert. In that case you don't need the `<` operator anymore.

Comment: @Biggytiny: You need to understand that std::map and std::set are internally implemented as balanced binary trees (red-black trees) and are internally sorted. This is what makes lookup logarithmically fast in these data structures. So if you use the tree-based std containers, you have to have a sorting order defined, e.g. a comparison operation for your map keys.